# Difference between shape and int_shape in Keras

Tags: keras

According to the Keras manual,

keras.backend.shape() returns the symbolic shape of a tensor or variable.
keras.backend.int_shape() returns the shape of tensor or variable as a tuple of int or None entries.

These definitions are still unclear to me. I couldn't find any relevant material in Google, either. Can anyone help me understand the difference between the two?

Answer (score 9):

```
import keras.backend as K 
import numpy as np

x = K.variable(np.eye(2, 2)) 

print('shape:', K.shape(x))
print('int_shape:', K.int_shape(x))
```

gives

> shape: Tensor("Shape_4:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
>
> int_shape: (2, 2)

As you can see, first one is a tensor (it contains two numbers of corresponding shape) whereas the second one is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question. In 'shape: Tensor("Shape_4:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)', why is the shape (2,) not (2,2)?

Comment: Because it contains two numbers - it contains (2, 2), which, as a vector, has shape (2,)

Comment: @DSKim I guess, It's like count of dimensions in shape. For e.g. if a tensor has actual shape:  (2,5,1) then it shows: (3, )